# Swift willSet/didSet assignment?

Tags: swift, didset

I want to observe changes on couple of properties in my class by using the `didSet`/`willSet` API. However I'd like to keep my properties decelaration section clean, so I want to have separate functions for implementations of this logic.

Right now I have something like this:

```
var myProperty: SomeType {
    didSet {
        handleDidSetMyProperty()
    }
}
```

However this takes up 5 lines, which is quite a lot if you have more of such properties. It would be great if I could limit this to 3, for example like this:

```
var myProperty: SomeType {
    didSet = handleDidSetMyProperty
}
```

Is there a way in Swift to assign a function/closure to a property observer?

Comment: Yeah that's a pretty obvious solution but it's far from my definition of clean code ;)

Comment: I second this sense of cleanliness @user3581248, would be cool :)

Comment: do it properly with five lines.  "reducing lines" is nonsensical.  use only the standard idiom.

Comment: really you should have blank lines introducing each block

Comment: *"Syntactic sugar"*? It doesn't matter. Sorry for being judgmental, but two things matter most - (a) compiled code size, and (b) readability of said code. If 5 lines can be whittled down to 3 - or blown up to 50 while taking the same amount of memory space, then - again - code readability is all you should care about, white space and line count included. (BTW, this type of question belongs in code review (https://codereview.stackexchange.com( not here.

Comment: @dfd: It depends on what you ask. “Can I assign a closure to the property observer?” is *not* a code review question. “How can I write this shorter/better/...” might be, but would probably at the borderline of "stub/hypothetical code", code review requires  more context.

Comment: With respect to the closing vote: I would *not* consider the concrete question “Can I assign a function to a property observer?” opinion-based.

Comment: @dfd while I might have phrased the question poorly, I was not asking for an opinion on how to organise my code, rather for a way to assign a function/closure to a property observer, as Martin R noticed. Please check the updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. See [Declarations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html) in the Swift 
Programming Language.

In “GRAMMAR OF A VARIABLE DECLARATION” you'll find

```
didSet-clause → attributes­opt ­didSet­ setter-name­­opt ­­code-block­
```

and in “GRAMMAR OF A CODE BLOCK”

```
code-block → {­ statements­opt }­
```

i.e. the `didSet` keyword can only be followed by a code block (with 
mandatory curly braces).